# NVIDIA CUDA requires a kernal version of 4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, My kernal version is 4.15. Is it a problem to install CUDA in this configuration?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

The [table](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#system-requirements) says that the required kernel version of Ubuntu 16.04.5 is (4.4)

when I `$uname -r` on my command line the output is `4.15.0-43-generic`

Last time I messed up my drivers and ended up having the freeze login issue, being the noob I am I had to reinstall Ubuntu because I couldn't fix it.

Is 4.15 kernel version acceptable for CUDA?
If not, How can I rollback to kernel 4.4?

Comment: In my book, "noob" and "CUDA" don't go together. What do you need Cuda for? Anyway, kernel 4.15 shouldn't be a problem (read the (**) in your own link ;))

Comment: I'm new to Linux (noob), also I'm CS student (need CUDA for Machine Learning related stuff, and I have to use Linux + CUDA because everybody in the team is using it)
And I have read the (**), it says that 4.13.x is supported as well as 4.4.x I was asking for 4.15 though..

Comment: 4.15 replaced 4.13 as the current HWE kernel version so it should be fine as well. But if it isn't the installer should give an error message and not install, you have nothing to loose here for trying.